# Increasing order total weight

Tags: rules, ubercart

Could some one tell me how I increase the weight of an order total using [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) module?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by increasing the weight of an order? Isn't weight equal to the sum of product weights?

Comment: ya absolutely. it is the sum of product weights. In my case i just want to add an extra weight to order total based on certain conditions. for eg if my total order weight= 1kg, i just want to add an extra weight of 150 gram.

Comment: ya..but can it be done with rules module?